# Getting Jenkins CI to control SupervisorD

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, .net-core, continuous-deployment, supervisord

So after years of using CruiseControl.NET for my continuous integration tasks, Iv'e finally decided to bite the bullet and succumb to the world of JavaCI, namely Jenkins.

Iv'e got my build system set up, and it mostly works accept for the last step, my deploy step, seems that I just can't get it to do what I want.

## What I'm trying to build

A dotnet core web application that consists of a C# back end using Microsoft's MVC technologies, and a front end written in TypeScript using the Aurelia web application framework.

The steps to build and deploy this application manually are

- dotnet restore
- npm install
- dotnet build
- dotnet publish
- service supervisor stop (Must be run as root)
- rm -R /web/app/* (Must be run as www-data or root)
- cp -R /buildoutput /web/app (Must be run as www-data or root)
- service supervisor start (Must be run as root)

The build system is running on a 64bit Ubuntu 16.04 instance, and jenkins is set up to poll the Git Repositiory holding the source code one every 5 minutes to check for changes.

## What Iv'e got so far

Every thing up to the "service supervisor stop" entry, works perfectly.  No matter what I try, I can't find a sane way to get the root steps to execute.

This is what I have in the Jenkins Job so far:

[image: Current Jenkins Project]

The "DeployFromJenkins.sh" shell script, is nothing magic, it simply has the following in: (Actual server paths have been censored)

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/sbin/service supervisor stop
rm -r /WEBAPPFOLDER/*
cp -R "/JENKINSBUILD/." /WEBAPPFOLDER/
/usr/sbin/service supervisor start
```

This version fails due to the fact that Jenkins runs as Jenkins, and thus tries to run the deploy script as jenkins, and that means no stopping/starting services.

Iv'e tried other ways too, small web app running as root for example, but I couldn't figure out how to make Jenkins send/receive URL requests, using a semaphore file, but I couldn't figure out how to make jenkins read/write the semaphore files.

Being new to using Jenkins, I'd take a pop at writing a plug in, but I don't have time, and I don't yet know Jenkins well enough to use it correctly, never mind learning it's API.

## So now to my question...

Whats the best way to achieve what I need to achieve, I know my way around Linux and Windows systems very well, so don't worry about suggesting crazy ideas.

I figure all I actually need to do is solve the deployment step, the rest works perfectly well, in which case what suggestions can folks make to do the deployment step better, is there a better plugin that I perhaps don't know about?

PS: I'm also not really a supervisorD expert either, I'm led to understand it can do more than I currently use it for which is simply just to start/stop and monitor jobs.

Thanks in advance.....

Comment: Have you tried using `su -c` or `sudo` in your `DeployFromJenkins.sh` script?

Comment: Funny enough, I never thought of that, and stumbled across a post this morning, which got me running. So I was just about to come in here and answer my own Question when I saw this comment :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So as always seems to happen, 8 hours later and I've managed to answer my own question.

The solution is amazingly simple.

**sudo**

Basically, you need to use your distro tools to add the following line to your sudoers file:

```
jenkins ALL = NOPASSWD: /path/to/yourscript.sh
```

On ubuntu this is done by using the *visudo* either as sudo, or from a root account.

I added my line just under the "root" entry in the section marked User privilege specification.

What this line essentially says is that, if the named script is run by the user jenkins with sudo in front it gets to run with full privileges and without needing a password.

Once this sudo entry is added in your distro configuration, then all you simply need to do is to set your post build step as follows:

[image: Updated post build step using sudo]

Using this technique I can now do lots of automation just using various shell scripts.